# Python Exception has occurred: OSError: No hay ningún proceso en el otro extremo de la canalización

Tags: python, api, instagram, instagram-api

Sucede que estoy haciendo un bot para instagram con una api llamada [instagrapi](https://github.com/adw0rd/instagrapi)
y estaba trabajando bien pero de un momento a otro me empezó a dar un error.
Pensé que tal vez era la cuenta asi que cambie las credenciales y usé otra cuenta pero el error es el mismo.

```
from instagrapi import Client
from threading import Timer
import random

# all of the parameters are in hours
max_follows=0
max_likes=0
max_comments=0
max_unfollows=0
max_direct_messages=0
client = Client()
client.android_device_id = "C61D4FE76F6642D4"

# stablish the maximuns
def get_parameters():    
    """Get all the max vars from the db folder
    """
    global max_follows,max_likes,max_comments,max_unfollows,max_direct_messages
    with open("db/maxs.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
        max_follows = int(lines[1]);
        max_likes = int(lines[3]);
        max_comments = int(lines[5]);
        max_unfollows = int(lines[7]);
        max_direct_messages = int(lines[9]);
        del lines
# stablish the credentials vars
def get_credentials():
    """get the credentials to login with 
    the 2 first lines of the credentials.txt
    """
    global user
    global password
    with open ("db/credentials.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
        user = lines[2];password = lines[3]         #choose the user credentials
        # user = lines[0];password = lines[1]
        del lines

# loggin  
def login():
    """logs in with the credentials
    """
    get_credentials()
    print("logged in?",(client.user_id!=None))
    client.login(
        username=user,
        password=password
        )
    print("logged in?",(client.user_id!=None));print(f"logged as {user}");

def follow_followers_random_page():
    with open ("db/pages_to_follow.txt", "r") as f:
        pages_to_follow_followers = f.read().splitlines()
        
        # for page in pages_to_follow_followers:
        page = random.choice(pages_to_follow_followers)
        print(f"starting to manage {page}")
        page_id=client.user_id_from_username(page)
        
        user_ids = []
        
        user_ids = list((client.user_followers(page_id,amount=max_follows*2)).keys())
        print("Founded ",len(user_ids)," people. Random choosing")
            
        while len(user_ids) > max_follows:
            #deletes random people until left just the ones we are going to follow
            index = user_ids.index(random.choice(user_ids)) 
            user_ids.pop(index)
        print(f"{len(user_ids)} people to be followed")
            
        del pages_to_follow_followers
        
        
    run = True
    user_number = 0
    time_between_follow = 3600 // max_follows
    while user_number < 199:
        Timer(time_between_follow + (random.randint(0,4)*10), lambda: client.user_follow(user_ids[user_number])).start()
        print(f"following {client.username_from_user_id(user_ids[user_number])}")
        user_number+=1

get_parameters()    
get_credentials()
login()
follow_followers_random_page()
# shutdown /s /t 3500
```

el error me lo da en la esta parte:

```
 print("logged in?",(client.user_id!=None));print(f"logged as {user}");
```

y cuando comento la linea se va para acá:

```
print("Founded ",len(user_ids)," people. Random choosing")
```

el codigo:

- obtine los parametros   (bien)
- obtine las credenciales (bien)
- Se logea en instagram   (bien)

incluso en le depurador muestra que la lista `users_ids` obtiene 400 ids

nombre y apellido del error:

```
Exception has occurred: OSError
[WinError 233] No hay ningún proceso en el otro extremo de la canalización
  File "C:\Users\jjhue\Documents\1)bot\bot instagrapi\bot.py", line 64, in follow_followers_random_page
    print("Founded ",len(user_ids)," people. Random choosing")
  File "C:\Users\jjhue\Documents\1)bot\bot instagrapi\bot.py", line 86, in <module>
    follow_followers_random_page()
```

antes funcionaba bien y ahora no (literal lo corri una vez, da un error, lo vuelvo a correr y pasa esto)
que pudo haber cambiado?
de antemano, gracias :)

Comment: +1 Por una pregunta bien formulada.

Comment: Pero cuál es el error que te da? El que figura en el título de la pregunta no parece estar relacionado con lo que se ve en las líneas en las que dices que se produce el error. Especialmente la segunda, simplemente estás accediendo a una variable `user_ids` que ya fue inicializada, por lo que a priori no parece que sea la que está causando un error de comunicación. Creo que sería mejor si pegas (como código) el stacktrace completo de la excepción.

Comment: Mira, el error con nombre, apellido y acta de nacimiento:

Exception has occurred: OSError
[WinError 233] No hay ningún proceso en el otro extremo de la canalización
  File "C:\Users\jjhue\Documents\1)bot\bot instagrapi\bot.py", line 64, in follow_followers_random_page
    print("Founded ",len(user_ids)," people. Random choosing")
  File "C:\Users\jjhue\Documents\1)bot\bot instagrapi\bot.py", line 86, in <module>
    follow_followers_random_page()

Comment: Las variables `user` y `password`, que aparecen en estas líneas: `client.login(username=user, password=password)`, justo antes del error, no están ni declaradas ni definidas fuera del ámbito de las funciones... Las defines como globales, para poder escribir en ellas, dentro de la función `get_credentials`, pero fuera de ella no existen, por lo que no están accesibles en la función: `login`

Comment: Hola, ya verifique y esto paso:
Corri el codigo, da el error y verifico lo que recibe la función y en efecto recibe las credenciales y me da el error en esta linea
`print("logged in?",(client.user_id!=None));print(f"logged as {user}");
`
ahora, hago lo que me dices y *declaro las variables globales* y me da el mismo error, pero ahora en la linea: 
`print("Founded ",len(user_ids)," people. Random choosing")`
verifico tambien que valor tiene la variable que uso en el print y vale 400

Comment: Es mas que probable que la api que usas no sea confiable e/o instagram te bloquee

Comment: eso, he pensado, pero cambie la cuenta e igual me da error

Comment: Si ahora te devuelve el número de seguidores del usuario es que la conexión se produce correctamente, pero por algún motivo luego falla... Parece un fallo de conexión con la base de datos. En `Google` aparecen muchos casos con el mismo error en diversos sistemas; aunque en la página de `bugs` de `instagrapi` en `github` no he visto nada parecido.

Comment: Hola a todos de nuevo. Paso un dia y probe de nuevo el bot con otra cuenta para la que va destinado y en efecto *funcionó*, lo cambie a la cuenta para la que dio error en primero lugar y obtuve el error. Puedo concluir que el error esta en que de alguna manera el instagram bloqueo la ip desde donde actua el bot o algo asi...
Gracias por su tiempo

Comment: Despues de un par de días encontré que se puede solucionar usando un proxy al correr el bot. [Aqui](https://adw0rd.com/2020/03/26/sniffing-instagram-charles-proxy/en/) explican más al detalle y [este](https://www.charlesproxy.com/download/) es el proxy que me funcionó.